# Compiler error when compiling range-v3 const method

Tags: c++, c++17, range-v3

I want to use the `range-v3` library to provide access to a container-member of a class. There should be a mutable as well as `const` access.
Compiling the class below causes however a compiler error. If I comment the `const` method out, the the compiler has nothing to complain:

```
error: no match for ‘operator|’ (operand types are ‘const std::vector<SomeType> {aka const std::vector<SomeType, std::allocator<SomeType> >}’ and ‘ranges::v3::view::const_fn’)
```

What is the problem here?

```
class A
{
public:
    auto all() {
        return m_container
                | ranges::view::all_fn();
    }

    const auto all() const {
        return m_container
                | ranges::view::const_fn();
    }

private:
 std::vector<SomeType> m_container 
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the names of the views directly, not their underlying implementation details. The names of the views are `all` and `const_`, respectively:

```
auto all()       { return m_container | ranges::view::all; }
auto all() const { return m_container | ranges::view::const_; }
```

Note also that in your `const` member function, you don't need a `const_` view, since `m_container` is already going to be `const`-qualified. All you need is `all`:

```
auto all()       { return m_container | ranges::view::all; }
auto all() const { return m_container | ranges::view::all; }
```

Or, as [Casey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45651215/compiler-error-when-compiling-range-v3-const-method/45651318#comment78261060_45651318) suggests, just doing things the normal way is more direct and readable:

```
auto all()       { return ranges::view::all(m_container); }
auto all() const { return ranges::view::all(m_container); }
```

Comment: I think `return ranges::view::all(m_container);` is more readable than using  the pipe operator in this context.